# Transfer files using ssh

Tags: ssh, file-transfer, winscp

I am using ssh (WinSCP) to transfer some files from a server to my workstation.

The problem is that at some files I get disconnected. Always same files. I am the owner of the directory so I guess the file permissions is not a problem. (Also I set the permissions to 777). Is there a size limit or something like that?

Protocol is SFTP, server is 32bit machine. Files are 100MB tops.

Added:

Worked with Filezilla using ftp. This temporarily fix the problem but is not exactly a solution since maybe next time I won't have root access to create a ftp account

Comment: Some more information you should include:  What is the target operating system (also 32/64 bit)?  How large are the files?  What protocol are you using in WinSCP (It supports SFTP, SCP and SSH connections)?

Comment: You have enough free space right?

Comment: For setting read permissions for yourself, it is sufficient to do `u+r` on the file. You create potential problems by setting stuff 777. Don't.

Comment: Edited, added all u asked.

Comment: @Chopper about 1TB for 3 100MB files... should do :)

Comment: what version of winSCP are you using? I've had similar issues with 4.x. Try an older winSCP version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some options:

Try one problem file on its own

Try using another client (FileZilla?)

Try via a command line ?

Comment: Worked with filezilla using ftp. This temporarily fix the problem but is not exactly a solution since maybe next time I won't have root access to create a ftp account.

Comment: what about using filezilla with sftp?

Comment: Yeah, what @Jure1873 said.  FileZilla does SFTP just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Are the files that you get disconnected on quite large ? Perhaps you need to configure keepalive in winscp. In the  Login Dialog->Connection Section turn keepalives on by selecting one of the options. The default 30s should be sufficient for the time between keepalives.

Comment: I tried... same problem. The files are not large... are larger than the rest but not so large.

Answer (score 1):

Can you use another program than WinSCP for testing and set debugging / verbose mode on? Or maybe WinSCP has that too. It might give you good information about why the connection was dropped.

Comment: Any suggestion about what I should use?

Comment: pscp? From here: http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html

Answer (score 1):

Is this transfer going through a Firewall or Intrusion Prevention device?  They can easily cut connections based on flaky signatures, weird flags, etc.  it's also possible a Antivirus scanner could pull off the same thing.

Comment: Nothing like that... I guess is size related as most ppl suggested... but 100MB is quite small.

Answer (score -1):

I would compress the files into a tar ball. And then transfer just the one file across. It will be a lot quicker. Then SSH into the target server, and uncompressed it.

Comment: I get error if I try to copy the tar.